# Getting stdin without dropping a line in the terminal

Tags: c, multithreading

I have a multi-threaded application and am trying to format my output in the terminal with escape codes. The only issue I am having is that when gathering input, I cannot place an *output mutex* around `fgets` since it will block output until something is input. Consequently, there is this small window where other threads gain access to the *output mutex* and print before I can erase the newline created by `fgets` with `\b`.

Is there a way around this? Or is there a function in C that accepts input without entering a newline after pressing ENTER?

My code for input is as follows:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_stdout);

fflush(stdout);
printf("\33[2K\r");
printf("Accept input: ");
fflush(stdout);

pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_stdout);

memset(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);

pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_stdout);

buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\r\n")] = 0;
printf("\b");

pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_stdout);
```

Comment: You can always use `fread`.  But your terminal probably isn't going to send any data to your program until you hit enter, and `fread` will read the carriage return the same as `fgets`.  But it sounds like what you really want is to put your tty in raw mode.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Okay thanks, so there is no way to do it without changing the terminal mode?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Would it be fine to increase my chances by placing the `printf("\b");` right after the `fgets` statement, not enclosed by a mutex?

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean by "the newline created by fgets".  fgets does not create a newline.  It reads one in, and you overwrite it with a zero, but I suspect you're troubled by the fact that when you hit 'return', your tty prints that newline before it sends it to your program.  To avoid that problem, you will need to change the terminal's mode.